# Fama-Macbeth regression in Eviews

Tags: regression, asset-pricing, fama-french, eviews

I'm adding a new factor to Fama-French three-factor model. I have constructed portfolios and got 18 three-way sorted portfolios. 
Now, I think I have to do Macbeth procedure to test the model. I'm thinking of doing it on Eviews. I'm new to Eviews. If I get step by step guidance to the procedure, I would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There many add-ins you could add to your Eviews, see here: http://www.eviews.com/Addins/addins.shtml

Comment: I have added the add-ins already to the Eviews. But I'm not how to interpret the results.